# Symfony2 - Using multiple views with different controllers at the same time

Tags: php, symfony, view, controllers

So i'm new to Symfony and i've been struggling to understand something very basic.

Lets say I have 2 twig templates:
**1.** A list of blog posts
**2.** A list of top users

Now for the homepage I want to display those two views, But those two views are rendered by different controllers, And each view have different variables.

**So how could I display those two views for example in the same page?

Would I have to create one controller who will handle them both together?**

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Comment: @Cerad thank you! that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your twig file make call for the action method who render the other twig view

```
  {{ render(controller("YourBundle:Controller:actionMethodInsideYourController", { 'variable': 'value' } )) }}
```

Comment: @OK - Using embedded controllers results in a performance hit as basically each call to render controller is treated as a new request.  However, you will usually only notice the slowdown if your call render controller a few dozen times inside of a loop.  Three should be fine and as long as you can maintain your code then all is well.